# Bidirectional communication using Android Beam

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

in p2p mode.. I want to send a message from Android phone to NFC reader and send back a response (Like "successfully Received") from the NFC reader to the smart phone with a single tap.

now After the first beam from the phone, if i remove the phone from the reader and put it back on the reader, I can able to send back the response..Here i'm doing two taps.
But i want to do that bidirectional communication with a single tap. Is that possible..??

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 .(Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4) & ACR 122 NFC reader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what software you are using to control the ACR122. In principle, you can just push back an NDEF message from the reader, telling that the transfer was successful. There is no need to remove the phone and tap it again to the reader. Just call the appropriate function to make the reader do it.

Comment: Can we able to push back a response by using DATA_EXCHANGE 0x40 APDU command from the reader to phone with the same existing connection? 
Basically i'm using ismb-snep-java library to control ACR122 device with some modification.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of ismb-snep-java, but, yes, you should be able to push data back using the same existing connection. (When you don't send anything, the LLCP implementation should be sending keep-alive messages back and forth.)